# Resize image keeping both sizes on ratio

Tags: css, image, resize, alignment

I have a photo blog on the very final stages and this is the last problem I'm struggling with.
The layout has fixed menu bar on the right and the content flows on the right. When photo is opened from gallery page to it's own, it is supposed to be resized so that either side is not over (for example) 70% of the free space. But not just that. It should also stay in horizontal and vertical center of the right content div.
At this point everything works except when the image is a portrait it goes over the screen.

Is this possible to achieve with only CSS to please the few percent that has JS not activated?
If not, well thats not a deal breaker.

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left_column">
  </div>
  <div id="right_column_post">

      <div id="post_container">

        <img src="img.jpg" width="1000" height="750"/>

      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#left_column {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    z-index:100;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#right_column_post{
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:240px;
    position: relative;
}


#post_container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}

#post_container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}


#post_container img{
    max-width:70%;
    height:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

This is close: http://jsfiddle.net/jcAGj/ but it'll break the layout if implemented as is.

Comment: What do you mean "it goes over the screen?"

Comment: I mean the image makes the screen scrollable. The image is bigger than the "viewport" (right word ?)

Comment: I can't reproduce that in your demo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are actually looking for, but if you want to resize image in aspect ratio then do not give max-width and max-height both, if u do so then at a point it will loose its aspect ratio.

u can give width:100%;

Here i am giving width in percentage

```
    #left_column {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    z-index:100;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:red;

}

#right_column_post{
    height: 100%;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:45%;
    position: relative;
}


#post_container {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    display: block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}



#post_container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
} 
#post_container img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Check this link:
/*NEW LINK*/

http://jsfiddle.net/madhuri2987/jcAGj/2/

Hope this is what u were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite. When window is resized wide enough the content becomes scrollable and the image isn't centered.

I actually had width:100%; and height:auto; but I seems to posted some test code.

Comment: The new link still has the same problem. The content goes scrollable when viewport gets wide enough.

Comment: Like here, but the height should be set to 80-70%:
http://pexetothemes.com/demos/expression_wp/portfolio/kids-in-nature/

Comment: Any help? Even with javascript?

Comment: I tried to make some Js that would do only the resize, but this don't seem to work. I'm really no expert on this so I'd appreciate an advice:

http://jsfiddle.net/DJngT/

Comment: @user2264516 - check this for fullscreen - http://fiddle.jshell.net/jcAGj/20/show/light/
Code - http://jsfiddle.net/jcAGj/20/

Hope this is what u r looking for..

Answer (score 0):

I got it working ...kind of. I did a stripped down test page and it works:

http://tomiphotography.com/wp-content/themes/Photomi/Test/post-2.html

But when I use the same exact css in the main WP page the image ratio goes haywire and the image isn't centered????:

http://tomiphotography.com/?p=176

:(

Any idea what might be in WP that overrides some css?

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left_column">
  </div>

  <div id="right_column_post">

      <div id="post_container">

            <img src="http://tomiphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Ruka-viimeinen.jpg"/>


    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
 html {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    background: url(img/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom left;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


#left_column {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    z-index:100;
    width: 240px; 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color:#ff0000;

}


#right_column_post{
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:240px;
    position: relative;
}

#post_container  {
  position:fixed !important;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  top:8%;
  right:80px;
  bottom:10%;
  left:320px;
}
#post_container img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;    
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```